# MongoError when sorting a field using `filter-collection` in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm using [filter-collections by workpop @DoctorPangloss](https://github.com/Workpop/filter-collections), tables are rendered fine with configured default sorting. Then I tried implementing `sortable table headers`, however I got following errors when clicking table headers.

```
I20150329-10:08:13.439(-7)? Got exception while polling query: MongoError: QueryFailure flag set on getmore command
I20150329-10:08:14.004(-7)? Got exception while polling query: MongoError: QueryFailure flag set on getmore command
I20150329-10:08:14.555(-7)? Got exception while polling query: MongoError: QueryFailure flag set on getmore command
I20150329-10:08:15.130(-7)? Got exception while polling query: MongoError: QueryFailure flag set on getmore command
I20150329-10:08:15.706(-7)? Got exception while polling query: MongoError: QueryFailure flag set on getmore command
I20150329-10:08:16.304(-7)? Got exception while polling query: MongoError: QueryFailure flag set on getmore command
I20150329-10:08:16.877(-7)? Got exception while polling query: MongoError: QueryFailure flag set on getmore command
I20150329-10:08:17.430(-7)? Got exception while polling query: MongoError: QueryFailure flag set on getmore command
I20150329-10:08:18.007(-7)? Got exception while polling query: MongoError: QueryFailure flag set on getmore command
^Cfish: Job 1, 'meteor' terminated by signal SIGINT (Quit request from job control (^C))
```

The template for `<th>` was correctly rendered as something like`<th class="fc-sort" data-fc-sort="date"> date </th>`.

The collection I'm dealing with is not big, only 3000 entries. And the field to be sorted was indexed in mongodb.

Not sure whether it's resulting from package conflicts. Current packages I'm using in Meteor:

```
accounts-password                    1.1.0  Password support for accounts
doctorpangloss:filter-collections    0.2.6  Filter, paging and sort for Meteor collections with hooks and Iron Router support.
fezvrasta:bootstrap-material-design  0.3.0  FezVrasta's Bootstrap theme implementing Google's Material (Paper) Design
insecure                             1.0.3  Allow all database writes by default
iron:router                          1.0.7  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
less                                 1.0.13  The dynamic stylesheet language
meteor-platform                      1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
meteorhacks:aggregate                1.2.1  Proper MongoDB aggregations support for Meteor
npvn:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3         1.1.13  accounts-ui re-styled to play well with Material Design.
tmeasday:publish-counts              0.3.4  Publish the count of a cursor, in real time
u2622:persistent-session             0.3.1  Persistently store Session data on the client
```

Comment: I'm also struggling with this error message. When it appears our system gets really slow. We don't use the filters collection. I found this issue https://github.com/Automattic/monk/issues/107 which indicates that you might need an index on the sortable fields

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by deleting the file `mongod.lock` located in `.meteor/local/db` folder inside your project.